# R update values based on event

Tags: r, date, time, dataframe

I recently posted this question already related to my Mysql database which I am using locally on my laptop. Since I did not find a solution to the problem in Mysql and others did not seem to find one either I would like to post it again but now related to R. I use the database with the "RMysql" package. Here is the problem:

I have a database table that contain data of different farming pratices during several years on several fields. Farmers entered there information based on the dates when a certain activity was done. A simplified example would look like this, where ID is an auto-increment value.

```
ID|Field|Date      |Activity  |
 1|A    |2012/08/01|Tillage   |
 2|A    |2012/08/24|Seeding   |
 3|A    |2013/03/05|Spraying  |
 4|A    |2013/03/05|Fertilizer|
 5|A    |2013/07/25|Harvest   |
 6|B    |2012/09/01|Tillage   |
 7|B    |2012/09/05|Seeding   |
 8|B    |2013/04/05|Spraying  |
 9|B    |2013/07/28|Harvest   |
10|B    |2010/08/24|Tillage   |
11|B    |2010/09/29|Seeding   |
12|B    |2011/05/01|Fertilizer|
13|B    |2011/07/12|Harvest   |
14|A    |2011/09/01|Seeding   |
15|A    |2011/10/10|Spraying  |
16|A    |2012/04/10|Fertilizer|
17|A    |2012/08/02|Harvest   |
```

Now I would like to add a column called "Season" that contains only the year when a field was harvested but is automatically updated for all other activites between the last harvest and this harvest for individual fields. Note that harvest dates are different for different fields.Another point is that the seeding was maybe done in 2011 but the field was harvested in 2012 and all this should then be called season 2012. In this example the output would ideally look like:

```
ID|Field|Date      |Activity  |Season
 1|A    |2012/08/01|Tillage   |2013
 2|A    |2012/08/24|Seeding   |2013
 3|A    |2013/03/05|Spraying  |2013
 4|A    |2013/03/05|Fertilizer|2013
 5|A    |2013/07/25|Harvest   |2013
 6|B    |2012/09/01|Tillage   |2013
 7|B    |2012/09/05|Seeding   |2013
 8|B    |2013/04/05|Spraying  |2013
 9|B    |2013/07/28|Harvest   |2013
10|B    |2010/08/24|Tillage   |2011
11|B    |2010/09/29|Seeding   |2011
12|B    |2011/05/01|Fertilizer|2011
13|B    |2011/07/12|Harvest   |2011
14|A    |2011/09/01|Seeding   |2012
15|A    |2011/10/10|Spraying  |2012
16|A    |2012/04/10|Fertilizer|2012
17|A    |2012/08/02|Harvest   |2012
```

Can anyone help?

**EDIT:**

What would I need to change if I start recording more information and give all "Activities" a separate column?
I tried:

```
DF <- read.table(text="ID|Field|Date      |Tillage|Seeding|Fertilizer|Spraying|Harvest
 1|A    |2012/08/01|Plough   |NA|NA|NA|NA
 2|A    |2012/08/24|NA   |Wheat|NA|NA|NA
 3|A    |2013/03/05|NA  |NA|NA|ProduktA|NA
 4|A    |2013/03/05|NA|NA|TypeB|NA|NA
 5|A    |2013/07/25|NA   |NA|NA|NA|9t
 6|B    |2012/09/01|Plough   |NA|NA|NA|NA
 7|B    |2012/09/05|NA   |Barley|NA|NA|NA
 8|B    |2013/04/05|NA  |NA|NA|ProductB|NA
 9|B    |2013/07/28|NA   |NA|NA|NA|10t
10|B    |2010/08/24|Cultivator   |NA|NA|NA|NA
11|B    |2010/09/29|NA   |NA|NA|NA|NA
12|B    |2011/05/01|NA|NA|TypeB|NA|NA
13|B    |2011/07/12|NA   |NA|NA|NA|6t
14|A    |2011/09/01|NA   |Barley|NA|NA|NA
15|A    |2011/10/10|NA  |NA|NA|ProductC|NA
16|A    |2012/04/10|NA|NA|TypeA|NA|NA
17|A    |2012/08/02|NA   |NA|NA|NA|7t|", 
                 sep="|", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

DT <- data.table(DF)
DT[, Harvest:=gsub(" ", "", Harvest, fixed=TRUE)]
DT[, Date:=as.POSIXct(Date)]
setkeyv(DT, c("Field", "Date"))
DT[, Season:=cumsum(c("", !is.na(head(Harvest, -1)))), by=Field]
DT[, Season:=max(year(Date)), by=list(Field, Season)]
```

This does unfortunately not work. Can someone solve this,too?

Comment: Apparently, there is a flaw in the sample dataset. Tillage date of Field A in row 1 is 2012/08/01 while the harvest date of the same field in row 17 is 2012/08/02, one day *after* tillage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming there was a harvest recorded for each season on each field (a dangerous assumption, but otherwise I see no way to do this):

```
DF <- read.table(text="ID|Field|Date      |Activity  |
 1|A    |2012/08/01|Tillage   |
 2|A    |2012/08/24|Seeding   |
 3|A    |2013/03/05|Spraying  |
 4|A    |2013/03/05|Fertilizer|
 5|A    |2013/07/25|Harvest   |
 6|B    |2012/09/01|Tillage   |
 7|B    |2012/09/05|Seeding   |
 8|B    |2013/04/05|Spraying  |
 9|B    |2013/07/28|Harvest   |
10|B    |2010/08/24|Tillage   |
11|B    |2010/09/29|Seeding   |
12|B    |2011/05/01|Fertilizer|
13|B    |2011/07/12|Harvest   |
14|A    |2011/09/01|Seeding   |
15|A    |2011/10/10|Spraying  |
16|A    |2012/04/10|Fertilizer|
17|A    |2012/08/02|Harvest   |", 
                 sep="|", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(DF[, 1:4])
DT[, Activity:=gsub(" ", "", Activity, fixed=TRUE)]
DT[, Date:=as.POSIXct(Date)]
setkeyv(DT, c("Field", "Date"))
DT[, Season:=cumsum(c("", head(Activity, -1)) == "Harvest"), by=Field]
DT[, Season:=max(year(Date)), by=list(Field, Season)]
#     ID Field       Date   Activity Season
#  1: 14 A     2011-09-01    Seeding   2012
#  2: 15 A     2011-10-10   Spraying   2012
#  3: 16 A     2012-04-10 Fertilizer   2012
#  4:  1 A     2012-08-01    Tillage   2012
#  5: 17 A     2012-08-02    Harvest   2012
#  6:  2 A     2012-08-24    Seeding   2013
#  7:  3 A     2013-03-05   Spraying   2013
#  8:  4 A     2013-03-05 Fertilizer   2013
#  9:  5 A     2013-07-25    Harvest   2013
# 10: 10 B     2010-08-24    Tillage   2011
# 11: 11 B     2010-09-29    Seeding   2011
# 12: 12 B     2011-05-01 Fertilizer   2011
# 13: 13 B     2011-07-12    Harvest   2011
# 14:  6 B     2012-09-01    Tillage   2013
# 15:  7 B     2012-09-05    Seeding   2013
# 16:  8 B     2013-04-05   Spraying   2013
# 17:  9 B     2013-07-28    Harvest   2013
```

PS: I think this should also be possible (and more efficient) with a rolling join, but couldn't see immediately how to do that.

Comment: Thank you. That does exactly what I was looking for. What would I need to change if I modify the design of the table and give every "Activity" a separate column (See edits in the problem description)?

Comment: Look at the `reshape2` package or the reshape functions in the development version of the data.table package.

Answer (score 0):

(MSSQL)

If i understood your question this should work.
Change the columns accordingly.

```
SELECT DayName,CONVERT (DATE, Date) AS 'DATE' , 'DAY' =(SELECT TOP 1 DY.Date FROM
Dates DY Where DY.DayName IN (DA.DayName) Order by DY.Date Desc )FROM 
Dates DA
```

I tried in db with same scenario.

```
DayName DATE    DAY
Date         Not Supplied      1792-09-22   1792-09-22 00:00:00.000
Friday  04     January 1980    31 December 2100
Monday  09     November 2071       27 December 2100
Friday  18     January 1980    31 December 2100
```

Answer (score 0):

(R)

You seem to have an implicit reliance on the order of these lines of data since field "A" has two different sequences for which the only indication is the interposition of field "B" records.

```
dfrm <- read.table(text="ID|Field|Date      |Activity  |
 1|A    |2012/08/01|Tillage   |
 2|A    |2012/08/24|Seeding   |
 3|A    |2013/03/05|Spraying  |
 4|A    |2013/03/05|Fertilizer|
 5|A    |2013/07/25|Harvest   |
 6|B    |2012/09/01|Tillage   |
 7|B    |2012/09/05|Seeding   |
 8|B    |2013/04/05|Spraying  |
 9|B    |2013/07/28|Harvest   |
10|B    |2010/08/24|Tillage   |
11|B    |2010/09/29|Seeding   |
12|B    |2011/05/01|Fertilizer|
13|B    |2011/07/12|Harvest   |
14|A    |2011/09/01|Seeding   |
15|A    |2011/10/10|Spraying  |
16|A    |2012/04/10|Fertilizer|
17|A    |2012/08/02|Harvest   |",
         header=TRUE, sep="|", 
         colClasses=c("numeric","character","Date", "character", "NULL"), 
         stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

dfrm$SeqID <- cumsum( c(0, dfrm$Field[-1] != head(dfrm$Field, -1) ) )
```

This would give you the last year in a sequence:

```
dfrm$Season <- with( dfrm, format( ave(Date, SeqID, FUN= max) , "%Y") )
>   dfrm
   ID Field       Date   Activity Season SeqID
1   1 A     2012-08-01 Tillage      2013     0
2   2 A     2012-08-24 Seeding      2013     0
3   3 A     2013-03-05 Spraying     2013     0
4   4 A     2013-03-05 Fertilizer   2013     0
5   5 A     2013-07-25 Harvest      2013     0
6   6 B     2012-09-01 Tillage      2013     1
7   7 B     2012-09-05 Seeding      2013     1
8   8 B     2013-04-05 Spraying     2013     1
9   9 B     2013-07-28 Harvest      2013     1
10 10 B     2010-08-24 Tillage      2013     1
11 11 B     2010-09-29 Seeding      2013     1
12 12 B     2011-05-01 Fertilizer   2013     1
13 13 B     2011-07-12 Harvest      2013     1
14 14 A     2011-09-01 Seeding      2012     2
15 15 A     2011-10-10 Spraying     2012     2
16 16 A     2012-04-10 Fertilizer   2012     2
17 17 A     2012-08-02 Harvest      2012     2
```

R data.frames are not normally displayed with "bars" as separators, but if you wanted to output such an object you can use `write.table` with sep="|".

```
write.table(dfrm, file="", sep="|", quote=FALSE, 
            row.names=sprintf("%3s" ,rownames(dfrm)))
ID|Field|Date|Activity|Season|SeqID
  1|1|A    |2012-08-01|Tillage   |2013|0
  2|2|A    |2012-08-24|Seeding   |2013|0
  3|3|A    |2013-03-05|Spraying  |2013|0
  4|4|A    |2013-03-05|Fertilizer|2013|0
  5|5|A    |2013-07-25|Harvest   |2013|0
  6|6|B    |2012-09-01|Tillage   |2013|1
  7|7|B    |2012-09-05|Seeding   |2013|1
  8|8|B    |2013-04-05|Spraying  |2013|1
  9|9|B    |2013-07-28|Harvest   |2013|1
 10|10|B    |2010-08-24|Tillage   |2013|1
 11|11|B    |2010-09-29|Seeding   |2013|1
 12|12|B    |2011-05-01|Fertilizer|2013|1
 13|13|B    |2011-07-12|Harvest   |2013|1
 14|14|A    |2011-09-01|Seeding   |2012|2
 15|15|A    |2011-10-10|Spraying  |2012|2
 16|16|A    |2012-04-10|Fertilizer|2012|2
 17|17|A    |2012-08-02|Harvest   |2012|2
```

In the absence of a specific need to

Answer (score 0):

#### Next Observation Carried Backward

Just by chance, I came across this question and I wondered why no one had suggested an *NOCB (Next Observation Carried Backward)* approach which easily can be implemented using the `na.locf()` function from the `zoo` package:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)[Activity == "Harvest", Season := year(Date)][]
DF[, Season := zoo::na.locf0(Season, fromLast = TRUE)][]
```

> ```
>     ID Field       Date   Activity Season
>  1:  1     A 2012/08/01    Tillage   2013
>  2:  2     A 2012/08/24    Seeding   2013
>  3:  3     A 2013/03/05   Spraying   2013
>  4:  4     A 2013/03/05 Fertilizer   2013
>  5:  5     A 2013/07/25    Harvest   2013
>  6:  6     B 2012/09/01    Tillage   2013
>  7:  7     B 2012/09/05    Seeding   2013
>  8:  8     B 2013/04/05   Spraying   2013
>  9:  9     B 2013/07/28    Harvest   2013
> 10: 10     B 2010/08/24    Tillage   2011
> 11: 11     B 2010/09/29    Seeding   2011
> 12: 12     B 2011/05/01 Fertilizer   2011
> 13: 13     B 2011/07/12    Harvest   2011
> 14: 14     A 2011/09/01    Seeding   2012
> 15: 15     A 2011/10/10   Spraying   2012
> 16: 16     A 2012/04/10 Fertilizer   2012
> 17: 17     A 2012/08/02    Harvest   2012
> ```

#### Rolling join

As of version 1.9.2 (on CRAN 27 Feb 2014), `data.table` has gained the ability to do *rolling joins*.

Here, first a helper data.table with the harvest dates and the `Season` is created

```
DF[Activity == "Harvest", .(Date, Season = year(Date))]
```

> ```
>          Date Season
> 1: 2013/07/25   2013
> 2: 2013/07/28   2013
> 3: 2011/07/12   2011
> 4: 2012/08/02   2012
> ```

which is then left joined with `DF`

```
DF[Activity == "Harvest", .(Field, Date, Season = year(Date))][
  DF, on = .(Field, Date), roll = -Inf]
```

> ```
>     Field       Date Season ID   Activity
>  1:     A 2012/08/01   2012  1    Tillage
>  2:     A 2012/08/24   2013  2    Seeding
>  3:     A 2013/03/05   2013  3   Spraying
>  4:     A 2013/03/05   2013  4 Fertilizer
>  5:     A 2013/07/25   2013  5    Harvest
>  6:     B 2012/09/01   2013  6    Tillage
>  7:     B 2012/09/05   2013  7    Seeding
>  8:     B 2013/04/05   2013  8   Spraying
>  9:     B 2013/07/28   2013  9    Harvest
> 10:     B 2010/08/24   2011 10    Tillage
> 11:     B 2010/09/29   2011 11    Seeding
> 12:     B 2011/05/01   2011 12 Fertilizer
> 13:     B 2011/07/12   2011 13    Harvest
> 14:     A 2011/09/01   2012 14    Seeding
> 15:     A 2011/10/10   2012 15   Spraying
> 16:     A 2012/04/10   2012 16 Fertilizer
> 17:     A 2012/08/02   2012 17    Harvest
> ```

Note that the rolling join has exhibited a flaw in the sample dataset which has *not* been detected by the other methods. Row 1 shows `Season` 2012 although the subsequent harvest (according to OP's `ID`) should be in 2013. Reason for this is that the dates for tillage and harvest are intermixed for field `A`. Tillage date of Field A in row 1 is 2012/08/01 while the harvest date of the same field in row 17 is 2012/08/02, one day *after* tillage.

#### Caveat

Note that both approaches rely on the implicit assumption that the rows are ordered such that for each `Field` and `Season` the last `Activity` is `Harvest`. Otherwise, `DF` needs to be ordered accordingly using `order(Field, Date)`.

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
DF <- fread(
  "ID|Field|Date      |Activity  |
 1|A    |2012/08/01|Tillage   |
 2|A    |2012/08/24|Seeding   |
 3|A    |2013/03/05|Spraying  |
 4|A    |2013/03/05|Fertilizer|
 5|A    |2013/07/25|Harvest   |
 6|B    |2012/09/01|Tillage   |
 7|B    |2012/09/05|Seeding   |
 8|B    |2013/04/05|Spraying  |
 9|B    |2013/07/28|Harvest   |
10|B    |2010/08/24|Tillage   |
11|B    |2010/09/29|Seeding   |
12|B    |2011/05/01|Fertilizer|
13|B    |2011/07/12|Harvest   |
14|A    |2011/09/01|Seeding   |
15|A    |2011/10/10|Spraying  |
16|A    |2012/04/10|Fertilizer|
17|A    |2012/08/02|Harvest   |", drop = 5L)
```