# R update values based on event based on multiple columns

Tags: r, date, dataframe, data.table

I recently asked a similar question [here](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/21077956/r-update-values-based-on-event) for having all "Activities" in one column. The solution provided worked very well. Now I would like to change something in the design to be able to record more detailed information. The table shows information recorded from different fields over several years. All activities on the fields are recored by date. Now I would like to add a "Season" column that groups all values belonging to a harvest season. As harvest season I define the time in between two harvest events. (see table at the bottom on how the result should look like). The problem here is that seeding is sometimes done in the previous year (e.g.2012) but fields are harvested in 2013. All events would need to be grouped as 2013.

What would I need to change if I start recording more information and give all "Activities" a separate column? I tried:

```
    library(data.table)

DF <- read.table(text="ID|Field|Date      |Tillage|Seeding|Fertilizer|Spraying|Harvest
 1|A    |2012/08/01|Plough   |NA|NA|NA|NA
 2|A    |2012/08/24|NA   |Wheat|NA|NA|NA
 3|A    |2013/03/05|NA  |NA|NA|ProduktA|NA
 4|A    |2013/03/05|NA|NA|TypeB|NA|NA
 5|A    |2013/07/25|NA   |NA|NA|NA|9t
 6|B    |2012/09/01|Plough   |NA|NA|NA|NA
 7|B    |2012/09/05|NA   |Barley|NA|NA|NA
 8|B    |2013/04/05|NA  |NA|NA|ProductB|NA
 9|B    |2013/07/28|NA   |NA|NA|NA|10t
10|B    |2010/08/24|Cultivator   |NA|NA|NA|NA
11|B    |2010/09/29|NA   |NA|NA|NA|NA
12|B    |2011/05/01|NA|NA|TypeB|NA|NA
13|B    |2011/07/12|NA   |NA|NA|NA|6t
14|A    |2011/09/01|NA   |Barley|NA|NA|NA
15|A    |2011/10/10|NA  |NA|NA|ProductC|NA
16|A    |2012/04/10|NA|NA|TypeA|NA|NA
17|A    |2012/08/02|NA   |NA|NA|NA|7t|", 
                 sep="|", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

DT <- data.table(DF)
DT[, Harvest:=gsub(" ", "", Harvest, fixed=TRUE)]
DT[, Date:=as.POSIXct(Date)]
setkeyv(DT, c("Field", "Date"))
DT[, Season:=cumsum(c("", !is.na(head(Harvest, -1)))), by=Field]
DT[, Season:=max(year(Date)), by=list(Field, Season)]
```

However, that seems not to work. The result should look like this with a "season" column at the end that indicates the season:

```
ID|Field|Date      |Tillage|Seeding|Fertilizer|Spraying|Harvest|Season
1|A    |2012/08/01|Plough   |NA|NA|NA|NA|2013
 2|A    |2012/08/24|NA   |Wheat|NA|NA|NA|2013
 3|A    |2013/03/05|NA  |NA|NA|ProduktA|NA|2013
 4|A    |2013/03/05|NA|NA|TypeB|NA|NA|2013
 5|A    |2013/07/25|NA   |NA|NA|NA|9t|2013
 6|B    |2012/09/01|Plough   |NA|NA|NA|NA|2013
 7|B    |2012/09/05|NA   |Barley|NA|NA|NA|2013
 8|B    |2013/04/05|NA  |NA|NA|ProductB|NA|2013
 9|B    |2013/07/28|NA   |NA|NA|NA|10t|2013
10|B    |2010/08/24|Cultivator   |NA|NA|NA|NA|2011
11|B    |2010/09/29|NA   |NA|NA|NA|NA|2011
12|B    |2011/05/01|NA|NA|TypeB|NA|NA|2011
13|B    |2011/07/12|NA   |NA|NA|NA|6t|2011
14|A    |2011/09/01|NA   |Barley|NA|NA|NA|2012
15|A    |2011/10/10|NA  |NA|NA|ProductC|NA|2012
16|A    |2012/04/10|NA|NA|TypeA|NA|NA|2012
17|A    |2012/08/02|NA   |NA|NA|NA|7t||2012
```

Comment: As I wrote in reply to your comment in the other post, the obvious solution would be reshaping the data to long format. I don't see the reason to keep it in wide format as the data is quite sparse and you don't need all these `NA` values.

Comment: I agree with Roland. Btw: i) `fread` is more convenient than `read.table`, you can pass a string of data to it just like you've done here and ii) please don't say "seems not to work", that's not very helpful to us. What exactly is wrong; is there an error message or what is the wrong output?

Comment: In addition to the advise from Roland and Matt, note that you are coercing `Season` into a string.  If you want to pad `cumsum` use `NA` not `""`.   As in `cumsum(c(NA_real_, !is.na(head(Harvest, -1))))`

Comment: Apparently, there is a flaw in the sample dataset. Tillage date of Field A in row 1 is 2012/08/01 while the harvest date of the same field in row 17 is 2012/08/02, one day *after* tillage.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference to OP's [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21077956/3817004) is that there are some additional columns and that the condition for extracting the harvest dates for applying [my  *rolling join* answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48197534/3817004) needs to be amended:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)[!is.na(Harvest), .(Field, Date, Season = year(Date))][
  DF, on = .(Field, Date), roll = -Inf]
```

> ```
>     Field       Date Season ID    Tillage Seeding Fertilizer Spraying Harvest
>  1:     A 2012/08/01   2012  1     Plough      NA         NA       NA      NA
>  2:     A 2012/08/24   2013  2         NA   Wheat         NA       NA      NA
>  3:     A 2013/03/05   2013  3         NA      NA         NA ProduktA      NA
>  4:     A 2013/03/05   2013  4         NA      NA      TypeB       NA      NA
>  5:     A 2013/07/25   2013  5         NA      NA         NA       NA      9t
>  6:     B 2012/09/01   2013  6     Plough      NA         NA       NA      NA
>  7:     B 2012/09/05   2013  7         NA  Barley         NA       NA      NA
>  8:     B 2013/04/05   2013  8         NA      NA         NA ProductB      NA
>  9:     B 2013/07/28   2013  9         NA      NA         NA       NA     10t
> 10:     B 2010/08/24   2011 10 Cultivator      NA         NA       NA      NA
> 11:     B 2010/09/29   2011 11         NA      NA         NA       NA      NA
> 12:     B 2011/05/01   2011 12         NA      NA      TypeB       NA      NA
> 13:     B 2011/07/12   2011 13         NA      NA         NA       NA      6t
> 14:     A 2011/09/01   2012 14         NA  Barley         NA       NA      NA
> 15:     A 2011/10/10   2012 15         NA      NA         NA ProductC      NA
> 16:     A 2012/04/10   2012 16         NA      NA      TypeA       NA      NA
> 17:     A 2012/08/02   2012 17         NA      NA         NA       NA      7t
> ```

Note that the rolling join has exhibited a flaw in the sample dataset. Row 1 shows Season 2012 although the subsequent harvest (according to OP's ID) should be in 2013. Reason is that the dates for tillage and harvest are intermixed for field A. Tillage date of Field A in row 1 is 2012/08/01 while the harvest date of the same field in row 17 is 2012/08/02, one day *after* tillage.

In case the column order is important, the `setcolorder()` function can be used to order the columns in place, i.e., without copying:

```
result <- setDT(DF)[!is.na(Harvest), .(Field, Date, Season = year(Date))][
  DF, on = .(Field, Date), roll = -Inf]
setcolorder(result, c(names(DF), "Season"))[]
```

> ```
>     ID Field       Date    Tillage Seeding Fertilizer Spraying Harvest Season
>  1:  1     A 2012/08/01     Plough      NA         NA       NA      NA   2012
>  2:  2     A 2012/08/24         NA   Wheat         NA       NA      NA   2013
>  3:  3     A 2013/03/05         NA      NA         NA ProduktA      NA   2013
>  4:  4     A 2013/03/05         NA      NA      TypeB       NA      NA   2013
>  5:  5     A 2013/07/25         NA      NA         NA       NA      9t   2013
>  6:  6     B 2012/09/01     Plough      NA         NA       NA      NA   2013
>  7:  7     B 2012/09/05         NA  Barley         NA       NA      NA   2013
>  8:  8     B 2013/04/05         NA      NA         NA ProductB      NA   2013
>  9:  9     B 2013/07/28         NA      NA         NA       NA     10t   2013
> 10: 10     B 2010/08/24 Cultivator      NA         NA       NA      NA   2011
> 11: 11     B 2010/09/29         NA      NA         NA       NA      NA   2011
> 12: 12     B 2011/05/01         NA      NA      TypeB       NA      NA   2011
> 13: 13     B 2011/07/12         NA      NA         NA       NA      6t   2011
> 14: 14     A 2011/09/01         NA  Barley         NA       NA      NA   2012
> 15: 15     A 2011/10/10         NA      NA         NA ProductC      NA   2012
> 16: 16     A 2012/04/10         NA      NA      TypeA       NA      NA   2012
> 17: 17     A 2012/08/02         NA      NA         NA       NA      7t   2012
> ```

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
DF <- fread(
  "ID|Field|Date      |Tillage|Seeding|Fertilizer|Spraying|Harvest
 1|A    |2012/08/01|Plough   |NA|NA|NA|NA
 2|A    |2012/08/24|NA   |Wheat|NA|NA|NA
 3|A    |2013/03/05|NA  |NA|NA|ProduktA|NA
 4|A    |2013/03/05|NA|NA|TypeB|NA|NA
 5|A    |2013/07/25|NA   |NA|NA|NA|9t
 6|B    |2012/09/01|Plough   |NA|NA|NA|NA
 7|B    |2012/09/05|NA   |Barley|NA|NA|NA
 8|B    |2013/04/05|NA  |NA|NA|ProductB|NA
 9|B    |2013/07/28|NA   |NA|NA|NA|10t
10|B    |2010/08/24|Cultivator   |NA|NA|NA|NA
11|B    |2010/09/29|NA   |NA|NA|NA|NA
12|B    |2011/05/01|NA|NA|TypeB|NA|NA
13|B    |2011/07/12|NA   |NA|NA|NA|6t
14|A    |2011/09/01|NA   |Barley|NA|NA|NA
15|A    |2011/10/10|NA  |NA|NA|ProductC|NA
16|A    |2012/04/10|NA|NA|TypeA|NA|NA
17|A    |2012/08/02|NA   |NA|NA|NA|7t")
```